# How to show $\int f\varphi=0 ~~\Rightarrow ~~f=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

As picture below , the $f=0$ means $||f||_{L^2}=0$ , but I don't know how to prove the theory below

> [image]

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $\Omega$? For instance, is it a locally compact Hausdorff space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ because otherwise it wouldn't make sense to talk about $\varphi$ being $C^\infty$. By the Riesz representation theorem, the dual of $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ is the space of finite Borel measures on $\Omega$. Then the functional $L:\varphi\mapsto\int_\Omega f(x)\varphi(x)\,dx$ is the zero functional, which means that $\mu=f(x)\,dx$ is the zero measure so $f=0$.

Comment: Could you explain what is dual of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ ? I don't know it .

Comment: Sure. Whenever you have a vector space, you may consider the set of bounded linear functionals on that space (functions from the vector space to the field that are linear and continuous). This set has the structure of a vector space as you can add and scale functionals to get another functional. The dual space is the space of these functionals. What Riesz representation says is that every object in the dual space looks like integrating against some finite Borel measure so we can identify the dual space with finite Borel measures. Would you like to see a proof that doesn't rely on the dual?

Comment: Thanks, I used to the dual space of a vector space is a vector space.  And seemly, Riesz representation says that continuous linear functional can be presented as inner. How to connect to Borel measure ?

Comment: Unfortunately there are a few theorems referred to as Riesz representation. I think you're thinking of the one about the dual of a Hilbert space but I have https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz–Markov–Kakutani_representation_theorem in mind.